# How do I know an ensemble of feed forward neural networks with different activations is a universal approximator?

Tags: neural-networks

Basically I took a look at [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.145.6041&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and it is clear that, "A standard multilayer feedforward network with a locally bounded piecewise continuous activation function can approximate any, continuous function to any degree of accuracy if and only if the network's activation function is not a polynomial."

Okay, great.  So now I know that, generally speaking, any single appropriate non-polynomial function used as the activation functions of a standard multilayered feedforward network is a universal approximator.

But in this scenario (and all the other's I have come across) all the activation functions of the network are the same.

My question is: How can I be certain that universal approximation will hold for a neural network which is an ensemble of two other networks, each with different activation functions (meeting the definition above)? Imagine using Sigmoid in one network and Tanh in another in such a way that each independently would meet the above criteria.

Clearly universal approximation seems to apply as people ensemble all the time, but how can we be certain it will always happen?

Comment: Are you worried that the ensemble network will be unable to approximate a function that one of its components alone could approximate?

Comment: No, there's too much evidence that an ensemble network will approximate appropriately if it's components will.  I am just shocked that I can't find a formal write up of this property anywhere proving it.  So I'd say I am really just interested in the proof itself, not ensemble networks being unable to approximate.

Comment: Well, if one component is a universal approximator and the other component(s) can represent the identity function, it follows immediately that the ensemble is a universal approximator.

Comment: Note that these approximation theorems are just about whether parameter assignments *exist* representing arbitrary functions. They don't say anything about convergence of learning algorithms.

Comment: That's a great point, I'm being a little lax with the semantics.  I'll adjust my question to remove reference to convergence.  For your first point I don't think I see that it follows immediately, but I get your point.  I think if you modified your statement slightly then we might be there: if one component is a universal approximator and the other component(s) can represent a function whose arbitrary combination with the universal approximator leaves the universal approximator unchanged, it follows immediately that the ensemble is a universal approximator.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. Is the identity function (i.e. output=input) not such a function? Or do we need to handle cases where the input and output spaces have different dimension? In those cases, a linear embedding (appending zeros) or projection (truncating the vector) should work.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I was just thinking about the difference between combining an "identity network" in an ensemble with the combination of two networks resulting in, let's say, the first network.  For example, suppose we have a network 1 (universal approximator), network 2 (identity function), and we combined them by summing their output to produce the ensembled output.  That is different than network 2 being 0 always.  In the second situation the combination is an identity combination (with neither networks being identity functions) where the result is network1.  Basically I agree with you, haha.

Comment: Ah! I was thinking of modular architectures like GANs where components are composed serially, but now I realize that "ensemble" usually means something else.

Comment: Ha, that's ironic b/c I'm pretty sure your answer still works.